# Why Semigroupal for types that have Monad instances don't combine?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am trying wrap my head around Semigroupals in Cats. Following are statements from "Scala with Cats" by Underscore.

> `cats.Semigroupal` is a type class that allows us to combine contexts

```
trait Semigroupal[F[_]] {
  def product[A, B](fa: F[A], fb: F[B]): F[(A, B)]
}
```

> The parameters `fa` and `fb` are independent of one another: we can compute them in either order before passing them to `product`. This is in contrast to `flatMap`, which imposes a strict order on its parameters.

So basically, we should be able to combine two `Either` contexts as well but that doesn't seem to work:

```
import cats.instances.either._ 

type ErrorOr[A] = Either[Vector[String], A]

Semigroupal[ErrorOr].product(Left(Vector("Error 1")), Left(Vector("Error 2")))

// res3: ErrorOr[Tuple2[Nothing, Nothing]] = Left(Vector("Error 1"))
```

If the USP of semigroupal is to eagerly execute independent operations, both eithers must be evaluated before being passed to `product` and yet we can't have a combined result.

> We might expect `product` applied to `Either` to accumulate errors instead of fail fast. Again, perhaps surprisingly, we find that `product` implements the same fail‐fast behaviour as `flatMap`.

*Isn't it contrary to the original premise of having an alternative approach to be able to combine any contexts of same type?*

> To ensure consistent semantics, Cats’ Monad (which extends Semigroupal) provides a standard definition of product in terms of `map` and `flatMap`.

*Why implement `product` in terms of `map` and `flatMap`? What semantics are being referred to here?*

> So why bother with Semigroupal at all? The answer is that we can create useful data types that have instances of Semigroupal (and Applicative) but not Monad. This frees us to implement product in different ways.

*What does this even mean?*

Unfortunately, the book doesn't covers these premises in detail! Neither can I find resources online. Could anyone please explain this? TIA.

Answer (score 5):

> So basically, we should be able to combine two Either contexts as well but that doesn't seem to work:

It worked, as you can see the result is a valid result, it type checks.

**Semigrupal** just implies that given an `F[A]` and a `F[B]` it produces an `F[(A, B)]` it doesn't imply that it would be able to evaluate both independently or not; it may, but it may as well not. Contrary to **Monad** which does imply that it needs to evaluate `F[A]` before because to evaluate `F[B]` it needs the `A`

> Isn't it contrary to the original premise of having an alternative approach to be able to combine any contexts of same type?

Is not really a different approach since `Monad[F] <: Semigroupal[F]`, you can always call `product` on any **Monad**. Implementing a function in terms of **Semigroupal** just means that it is open to more types, but it doesn't change the behavior of each type.

> Why implement product in terms of map and flatMap? What semantics are being referred to here?

TL;DR; consistency:

```scala
// https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/54b3c2a06ff4b31f3c5f84692b1a8a3fbe5ad310/laws/src/main/scala/cats/laws/FlatMapLaws.scala#L18

def flatMapConsistentApply[A, B](fa: F[A], fab: F[A => B]): IsEq[F[B]] =
  fab.ap(fa) <-> fab.flatMap(f => fa.map(f))
```

The above laws implies that for any `F[A]` and for any `F[A => B]` as long as there exists a **Monad** *(actually **FlatMap**)* for `F` then, `fab.ap(fa)` is the same as `fab.flatMap(f => fa.map(f))`

Now, why? Multiple reasons:

- The most common one is the principle of least surprise, if I have a bunch of eithers and I pass them to a generic function, no matter if it requires **Monad** or **Applicative** I expect it to fail fast, since that is the behavior of **Either**.
- Liskov, suppose I have two functions `f` and `g`, `f` expects an **Applicative** and `g` a **Monad**, if `g` calls `f` under the hood I would expect calling both to return the same result.
- Any **Monad** must be an **Applicative**, however an accumulating **Applicative** version of **Either** requires a **Semigroup** for the `Left`, whereas, the **Monad** instance doesn't require that.

> What does this even mean?

It means that we may define another type *(for example, [**Validated**](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html))* that would only satisfy the **Applicative** laws but not the **Monad** laws, as such it can implement an accumulating version of `ap`

---

Bonus, since having this situation of having a type that is a **Monad** but could implement an **Applicative** that doesn't require sequencing, is so common. The **cats** maintainers created [**Parallel**](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/parallel.html) to represent that.

So instead of converting your **Eithers** into **Validateds** to combine them using `mapN` you can just use `parMapN` directly on the **Eithers**.